# PHPMyAdmin Replace query values in a url

Tags: mysql, string, url, replace

I understand how to use the Replace function in MySQL to replace strings of text but when I try something like this I get 0 records updated. What am I missing?

```
UPDATE `pages_description` 
    SET `pages_body` = REPLACE(`pages_body`, "pages.php?pID=16&CDpath=4", "pages.php?pID=188&CDpath=0_4")
```

Answer (score 1):

It was the ampersand! OMG I needed to use the `&amp;` entity for it.
`pages.php?pID=16&amp;CDpath=4`
I also wanted to point out (for future reference) that you will have to change the delimiter to an unused character in PhpMyAdmin to use as is. I changed mine to a colon instead of a semicolon.
[image: Example of delimiter location.]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not finding any matches? Make sure you have everything spelled correctly. You can do a search like this to see if you get any results for the contents you are trying to replace.

```
SELECT `pages_body` FROM `pages_description` WHERE `pages_body` LIKE '%pages.php?pID=16&CDpath=4%'
```

The replace function is also case sensitive, so check for that too.

Comment: It returns Zero results still, which doesn't make sense because I am looking right at the url in the source code and copy/ pasting.

Comment: What is the data type for the `pages_body` column? Also, can you copy paste a sample entry so I can test it on my end?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you. The Pages body was using the ampersand entity in place of an actual ampersand, which is why it was not finding any matches.